# Iterate through a list and click element (Cucumber/Java)

Tags: java, cucumber

I have 20 buttons on a single page each one of these buttons has the similar ID of `id='gvFobs_DXSelBtn**'` where the `**` represents the position number of the button so `id='gvFobs_DXSelBtn01'` for position one and `id='gvFobs_DXSelBtn20'` for position 20.
I don't want to create a `WebElement` for each position. I am trying to find a way to list them iterate through each position until I reach the desired position and then click.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I have 20 buttons on a single page each one of these buttons has the similar ID...I don't want to create a `WebElement` for each position*

You will still need to create `WebElement` instances for each button. Obtaining a list of `WebElement` objects is not the problem. The problem is what happens after invoking `click()`. According to the *[WebElement API](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click())*

> *Click this element.* ***If this causes a new page to load, you should discard all references to this element and any further operations performed on this element will throw a StaleElementReferenceException***.

This is true for this component and any other `WebElement` reference obtained before the page reload. This is because after the click event, the entire DOM is invalidated and all `WebElement` references are considered stale (old) at that time.

What does this mean to you? It means that, if any of those buttons triggers a page reload, this approach won't work. It also mean that even if this solution works in this particular case, it is not guaranteed that it will work on every case and that you should use this approach judiciously.

I **strongly** recommend against it. The safest way to approach is to have steps to click each button independently.

Comment: That makes sense, I was trying to find a way to simplify it a bit as the page could eventually have up to 100 of those buttons. If I could have created a method where by I pass in a position number I could assign it to a webelement at the time of calling that method, however going by the information you have provided I think it will cause more problems than it would solve. 

Thank you very much!